# How to check two Session are the same?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have written a program by Python. I am using the requests library and want to set the Session.

I have tried to create a function for the network request,the arguments is url(str) and session object. (I have used the session for request a website)

The problem is: The session is not fixed (just my opinion). When I put the session argument to the function, the request will return the wrong page, but when I haven't use the function (I have use the threads with the function), I request another website with the session after the first request, the returned page is right. So I think the problem is the Session object is not the same in function's local Session and global Session, I want to check the sessions if same, how to do it?

My Mother tongue is not English, so the English is not good,please excuse.

code:

```
import requests
from tomorrow import threads
# create a session
s = requests.Session()

# the right code
# s.post(url1)
# s.get(url2)

# the wrong code
@threads(100)  # create threads
def request(url, session):
    return session.get(url)

s.get(url1)
req = request(url2, s)  # that will return a wrong page
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you have tried so far.

Comment: I have added the code.